# Twilio Notify Service SMS Bulk with Image

Tags: php, sms, twilio

Im trying to bulk SMS with the following

```
$notification = $client
            ->notify->services($appSid)
            ->notifications->create([
                "toBinding" => $binding,
                "body" => "000000000000000000000000000",
                "mediaUrl" => "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg"
        ]);
```

$binding is just an array of phone numbers.

But the mediaUrl doesn't show up in the received SMS.

mediaUrl dose work with $client->messages->create();
Help ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When sending media over MMS using Notify you need to specify the media as part of the SMS overrides (see the [documentation here on the options you can send when creating a notification](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notifications#sending-to-stored-bindings)).

So, in your case your code should look like this:

```
$notification = $client
        ->notify->services($appSid)
        ->notifications->create([
            "toBinding" => $binding,
            "body" => "000000000000000000000000000",
            "sms" => [
                "media_urls" => ["https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg"]
            ]
    ]);
```

Comment: Great news! Hope the rest of your app goes smoothly.

Comment: For anyone wanting to do this in node/javascript, it looks like this:

sms: {
      "media_urls": ['https://imageaddress.com/image.png']
    }

Comment: @NealJones awesome work, thanks for the node version.